# Android - google maps are not shown on device

Tags: android, google-maps

I've created my own keystore using this command from d.android:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias my_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Next I've found SHA1 using: keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-keystore
It was right after SHA1: ....

The in my app i have com.mypackagename.MyClassName

In the API Access of Google Api Console I've pasted the following:

```
MY_SHA1;com.mypackagename
```

And it was successfully added.

But when I am launching my app on the device I still have grey tile instead of map.
Although in

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="value_taken_from_Api_key_field_in_google_console">
```

And in fragment for map I also have pasted:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="value_taken_from_Api_key_field_in_google_console">
</fragment>
```

When I run my app straight from IDE using my device instead of emulator it shows grey screen (zoom buttons and "Google" label are shown).
Also when I create .apk using mentioned keystore with my_alias then this .apk also shows grey screen instead of map (zoom buttons and "Google" label are also shown).

Comment: Daniel's advice might be helping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device/30559898#30559898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. And it was because I have 64bit laptop and I used 32bit Win7. Now I have 64bit Win7 and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I personally had that problem once, seems my keytool wasnt working that great.
I know that eclipse has a function that shows your SHA1, which was different(and working) for me. It's at Window>Preferences>Android>Build. See if that one is different if you use eclipse.
Also, did you set the correct permissions, meta data(also google play services versions), glEs and such things, as shown in [the google maps getting started walkthrough](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)? I also dont think the `android:apiKey` is needed in your map fragment, since it is set in the manifest.

Comment: Oh... I use Intellij Idea 13. Do you know where I can find this? Google shows me nothing for that at now... And as for the manifest - yes I've added:
"android.permission.INTERNET"
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
"com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to find it in there. There probably is such a function in there though.. don't see a preferences window somewhere?

Comment: I fixed the problem. And it was because I have 64bit laptop and I used 32bit Win7. Now I have 64bit Win7 and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new debug API key using the debug keystore.  On Windows you can find the debug keystore at: `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.android\debug.keystore`

Use the SHA1 from that keystore and generate a new API key.  You should then be able to see the map when you run your app from the IDE onto you device.