# Why doesn't Google Map show on release key?

Tags: android, google-maps, authorization

Why doesn't Google Map show on release authentication key?

Before I use release key, it ran normally.

Here is my log:

```
09-10 11:01:25.361: E/b(21729): Authentication failed on the server.
09-10 11:01:25.361: E/Google Maps Android API(21729): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
09-10 11:01:25.391: E/Google Maps Android API(21729): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
09-10 11:01:25.391: E/Google Maps Android API(21729): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
09-10 11:01:25.391: E/Google Maps Android API(21729): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
09-10 11:01:25.391: E/Google Maps Android API(21729):   API Key: AIzaSyBiDi1b8SwwYsr08rbRtI6UJt71kwbZrNE
09-10 11:01:25.391: E/Google Maps Android API(21729):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 4F:B8:B5:15:F1:FB:2F:6D:27:00:2E:C4:91:B8:FE:E1:18:7D:46:80;bamb.nitaf.wedding
```

Comment: If you use separate signing keys for your release and debug versions of the app you must provide both keys in the developer console.

Comment: Do you know, you need to generate separate SSH key for release version

Comment: how to generate separate SSH key for release version?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used some different key in your manifest.  Please visit Google developers console and create your own api key for using Google maps in your application. As you can clearly see the terminal says the key doesn't exist.   Follow the below link to know more on this topic.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/google-maps/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure about the following things about Google Map V2:

1.Generating correct SHA-1 for your release key.

2.Generating the API key with the correct package name and the generated SHA-1

3.Defining the correct permissions in manifest.xml to access the map:

```
<permission
        android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

  <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="yourApiKey" />
```

4.Lastly enabling Google API MAPV2 in developer console.

In your case,I suspect that the SHA-1 for your releaese mode is wrong and hence the error.

Please see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) to generate API Key correctly.

Comment: I have been try to make my  release key. and I export sign application package with my release key that I've just made. fyi, I got API key By adding SHA1 from my release key and I put in to manifest.xml. But when I running the app it still show blank map. help me please.<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDfP3BxoB_w3DeUQEFg-Yy9djRtL2g****" />

Comment: Just make sure theSHA-1 for your release key is correct.Check the link I have provided to generate the SHA-1