# How to add Google Map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am an android learner. I have an issue related to `GoogleMap`. When I open the app I got blank map screen.

Here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/action_top_bar" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapview_events"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/event_locator_screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my error:

> 02-10 03:09:02.324 5644-5708/? E/Google Maps Android API:
>   Authorization failure.  Please see
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how
>   to correctly set up the map. 02-10 03:09:02.324 5644-5708/?
>   E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console
>   (https://console.developers.google.com)
>                                                             Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>                                                             Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>                                                                 API Key: AIzaSyAlA9K-HAA6p2xBTQtQkdIX-PbjZkygqLA
>                                                                 Android Application (;):
>   EC:36:6A:04:B1:7A:02:C5:33:45:C6:AC:9E:AC:9F:AA:FE:14:1B:C0;com.example.ajay.hot

Manifest`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/main_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.JAboutScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.MemberProfileScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.JContactUs"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.AddEventActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.JWebActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.JEventDetailsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.EventLocatorActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.EventDirectonsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ajay.hot.JSponsorsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />

    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAlA9K-HAA6p2xBTQtQkdIX-PbjZkygqLA" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <!-- Live    android:value="AIzaSyCXOfQlLbtSYF9ztdGLyiAoBl6Ts5YQkxQ" /> -->
    <!-- Test  android:value="AIzaSyB7aB015Msr5ZhV_Su_ePSZIQtDzMo4Kz8" -->

</application>
```

`

Comment: The solution is in your logcat itself: **Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492583/why-doesnt-google-map-show-on-release-key/32493379#32493379