# Google Maps API Android - map not appearing when using keystore

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I am able to run my app fine using the debug keystore - but when I attempt to run with the production version with a generated keystore - no map.

I have verified that everything is as it should be - API key - check! Keysrore SHA1 - check!

Log follows:

Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)

Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

API Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx

Android Application (;): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;xx.xxx

Comment: If you used a wizard to create your project or your Activity, this might be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device

Comment: Thanks but - no. I have this set in both places - properly.

Comment: Are you using one API key that has both debug and release SHA1 values, or are you using separate API keys for debug and release?

Comment: Tried both ways - grouped them and did as separate entries. I even tried two different Google Developer accounts as a sanity check. Wondering if this could have something to do with the keystore.

Comment: Try putting the release API key directly in the AndroidManifest and then create the signed apk.  If that doesn't work, then there is an issue with the API key itself.  If it does work, then there is an issue getting the correct value for the release build.

Comment: One more thing to check as well, is the SHA1 value you have in the API key exactly as it shows in the logs after `Android Application`?

Comment: Unclear why - but the release build now shows a map. May have been a matter of retracing steps one more time. Dunno - but thx for your help.

Comment: Nice! One last thing, whenever you make a change to the API key, be sure to fully uninstall the app and reinstall, that could have been the issue as well.