# Google Map do not show after build to apk and install in real device?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I build an app using Google Map API, when I run my app on virtual device, it worked normally, but when I built my project to apk file and installed it on real device, it had a problem, my app do not show the map.
I has already save the debug key and release key in Google Developer Console
[image: Debug key and release key saved]

I also enter API key in my project
[image: API key added to project]

I turned Google Map API enabled
[image: Google Map API enabled]

But my app is still not working in real device
[image]

Please help me. Thank you.
This is my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    // Setting a click event handler for the map
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            //mMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    });


    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        }
    });
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //add(groupId, itemId, order, name)
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "My Location");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case 1:
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            return true;

        default:
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably the same issue from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device