# google map didnt show on device

Tags: android, google-maps

I try to make sample google map project from [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/) tutorial. It's fine when I try this on android studio emulator but on my device it just shows a gray view with google company mark.

Of course I read a ton of articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device).

But I can't troubleshout where my problem is? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you upload screenshoot and its logcat?

Comment: @TruongHieu it works fine on emulator...but on device i just see a gray view with google company mark

Comment: You use debug version on real device or generate signed apk?

Comment: generate signed apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> generate signed apk

So you were wrong. You have to create 1 more key on Google Console for "release version" (singed apk) 'cos it is different than "debug version" which you install on emulator.

This answer on what you provide in your question will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30559898/4316327

> First, switch to Project view by using the dropdown in the upper left
>   of the Project Explorer. Then, expand app/src/, and you will see
>   subfolders debug and release. Under there, you should see two separate
>   google_maps_api.xml files under debug/res/values and
>   release/res/values.

Paste your "release version" key to `google_maps_api.xml` inside `release` folder.

If that folder is not exist, create one like `debug` folder.

Comment: I made another api key with my sha-1 and paste that in both xml but it still didnt work.maybe i should wait 5 minute.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your app to console google website to get API Keys to put it on your xml file. This is the most common error that the map doesn't show. API Keys are not correctly manifested.

Comment: i did this and i paste API key in 2 xml file

Comment: Do you double check your Sha-1?

Comment: google_maps_api.xml in release and debug folder.        whats Sha-1?