# Confused about SHA1 fingerprint

Tags: android, sha1

May be it is a stupid question, May be this question will be downvoted... But I must ask this to you guys.

I have two SHA1 Keys. One is generated from Android Studio. I've read somewhere that this is only for debug mode and I've to create a key store for release mode. So I've got another SHA1 key after creating a signed apk. I've found that if I sign in with the debug key it works fine when the app is being tested. But after releasing it to the play store, user cannot login with my app. I am planning to migrate to Firebase. Now which SHA1 key should I put in firebase app, so that I can test my app as well as release in play store? I see that I can add multiple keys in the app, how will my keys work after release?

Comment: Either add both SHA1 fingerprints to one API key, or use separate API keys for debug/release.  Either way, you will need to configure the appropriate API keys with the debug SHA1 and the release SHA1.  For using separate API keys, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30559898/4409409

Comment: You mean After I release my application to play store, I shall have to update the SHA1 fingerprint in Firebase?