# Google Map is not showing after uploading it to playstore

Tags: android

Firstly I created the app it was ok with debug key then I make the keystore and from the command prompt I got the sha1 key and with that key I got another key, then I add my project package name and sha1 key at google developer console from where I get the key. Then i add that key at src/release 'your key' then I made the signed apk and uploaded it to play store, i tried four times and now i am tired, google map not showing. At catlog it shows please check api key v2 is enabled and is the key AI.....8 exists. Can anyone suggest me what can i do? What am i missing?I tried all the suggestions mentioned in this web. Help Help Help :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Google map still blank on real Android device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk)

Answer (score 0):

How many time did you wait ? Sometimes it take about 1 or 2 days.

Did you receive a mail from Google ? There is maybe a problem of legal right in your app.

Did you get message when you upload your apk ?

Comment: Only IARC rating in mail and it's almost 36 hours no map :(. Its kinda app like uber where is the problem then.