# google map blank only at release (didn't work every comment on stackoverflow)

Tags: android, google-api

I've got blank screen only at release version.
(debug is fine.)
I've tried most of answer in stackoverflow... but it didn't works....
Please check below images.
I've put the key on debug & release xml and also make them list on console.developers.google.com.
What kind of things I can do more??

(And this is basic project what Android studio support which I can choose when I made new project at Android studio.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Lj9.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF71k.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

First check on your Google Map Console's account whether your API is restricted or public.

**if it is restricted for android** then you have to provide package name with SHA1.
you can generate your SHA1 from command prompt

```
keytool -export -alias YourAliasName -keystore "your_jsk_path" -list -v
```

and also after deploying on playstore you have to add that SHA1.
you can get that SHA1 from Release Management > App Signing >App Signing Certificate.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already made it restricted and  got SHA1. So I put release SHA1 on  console.developers.google.com. But it didn't works.... That's the problem!

Comment: you have to generate SHA1 from your system...Type this in command prompt `keytool -export -alias YourAliasName -keystore "your_jsk_path" -list -v`

Comment: For this project, 2 One for debug and another for release. is that right?

Comment: Of course I made SHA1 from my project, especially release SHA1 is from my keystore.

Comment: @dalami0i, Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk

Comment: 1 API is enough for 1 project..and if you are restricting for android then provide SHA1 which is generated from system and google console (after deploying).

Comment: @dalami0i generate from System not from project

Comment: @MaYurMahAjan Yeah, that's what I did. But it didn't works.... is there any other issue I need to check? (Of course I made it restricted for android).

Comment: @MaYurMahAjan Yes, I made SHA1 from my keystore as you typed "your_jsk_path".

Comment: API which you have restricted and enabled for release add that API in manifest meta-data and then try

Comment: @dalami0i, What problem are you facing?

Comment: @MaYurMahAjan Of course I restricted for android and get a API_KEY from console and put them at manifest meta-data. But it didn't works....

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty I made Map project as basic what Android studio support but only release version it shows blank with small logo at left-bottom. I want to get a map on release version