# Google Map doesnt render in Release mode

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, google-cloud-platform, react-native-maps

I've been using Google Maps API in debug mode and working fine all along until it's in Release mode. Correct me if I'm wrong, we need a separated API key for Google Maps if we wished to release our app.

[image]

I've done the following:

- Created new API key
- enabled billing account in my project at GCP

In order to extract the `SHA-1` key, I've navigated to `project/android/app` where I can see `myapp.keystore` and run the command `keytool -list -v -keystore mypp.keystore`.

After created the `API_KEY`, I've navigated to `project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and modify the key

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="xxxxxx"/>
```

What else could've been missing? Thanks in advance

Please notice that this is a `React-Native` project and there isn't a separated `Release` and `Debug` directory/path to configure the APIKEY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Google map still blank on real Android device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk)

Comment: are you using mac or windows system ?

Comment: @Quicklearner: Mac

Comment: @SolulabInc.: It's different than that question because for I don't see `Release` nor `Debug` folder under `src` which I believed it is combined by React Native

Comment: check my answer dear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

a) Open android studio. Build --> Generate Signed APK and click Next

b) Copy your `keystore` path and key `alias`.

[image]

c) Now Open terminal and enter:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"
```

d) Enter your key password and this will print out your release SHA1.

e) Then use this SHA1 in google project , Paste it in there and save changes, now run the app again to load map

> Update:-

To generate `debug` key 
Do this

a) Click on the Gradle tab on the right option bar

b) Go to the root folder -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport

c) Double click, this will build with the signingReport and post in your bottom view your SHA1.

Comment: I've mentioned that I do have keystore `myapp.keystore` run the command `keytool -list -v -keystore mypp.keystore` will show me the keystore's SHA-1

Comment: Your answer is suggesting me to re-gen a new keystore but it's hard to convince that the problem is coming from a faulty keystore

Comment: you should cross check it dear :) and you should generate the Release and debug key both to cross verify at your end

Answer (score 1):

There should be separated keys for `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` versions. If you create `Google Maps Activity` in Android Studio it will create separated resource files `google_maps_api.xml` with API_KEY value. As you can see debug and realease versions has different `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint`, what means theirs keys shouldn't be same.

Of course, It means that mentioned code in manifest should be changed to resources reference.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

And key files should be at followed directories:

`src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml`

`src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml`

Comment: Many thanks for trying to help out. I understand your point but lets say I'm just trying to make it work for release minimally. I've use the `RELEASE` version's `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` to create a new API_KEY, so isn't that enough?

Comment: You said maps working in debug mode. It means your key is created for debug. Or are you saying you already created release key and it doesn't work?

Comment: During development period the map was working. Now that I'm focusing just on releasing the app, I've not tested this new key with debug mode

Comment: Main point is to use debug key in debug version and release key in release version. I added to my answer directories for resource files, so if you still don't have them you can create.

Comment: I do aware about the different path between debug and release. However this is a ReactNative project which is crossplatform. The path for Native Android is handled by RN and I don't see debug path nor release path. There is only a standard AndroidManifest.xml