# Displaying the release certificate fingerprint only shows (SHA-256), not SHA1

Tags: android, ssl, apk, google-maps-android-api-2, sha1

I am following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup, specifically these instructions:

> Displaying the release certificate fingerprint Locate your release
>   certificate keystore file. There is no default location or name for
>   the release keystore. If you don't specify one when you build your app
>   for release, the build will leave your .apk unsigned, and you'll have
>   to sign it before you can publish it. For the release certificate, you
>   also need the certificate's alias and the passwords for the keystore
>   and the certificate. You can list the aliases for all the keys in a
>   keystore by entering:
>
> keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name Replace your_keystore_name
>   with the fully-qualified path and name of the keystore, including the
>   .keystore extension. You'll be prompted for the keystore's password.
>   Then keytool displays all the aliases in the keystore.
>
> Enter the following at a terminal or command prompt:
>
> keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
>   Replace your_keystore_name with the fully-qualified path and name of
>   the keystore, including the .keystore extension. Replace
>   your_alias_name with the alias that you assigned to the certificate
>   when you created it.
>
> You should see output similar to this:
>
> Alias name:  Creation date: Feb 02, 2013 Entry type:
>   PrivateKeyEntry Certificate chain length: 1 Certificate[1]: Owner:
>   CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android,
>   C=US Serial number: 4cc9b300 Valid from: Mon Feb 02 08:01:04 UTC 2013
>   until: Mon Feb 02 18:05:04 PST 2033 Certificate fingerprints:
>       MD5:  AE:9F:95:D0:A6:86:89:BC:A8:70:BA:34:FF:6B:AC:F9
>       SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
>       Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
>       Version: 3 The line that begins with SHA1 contains the certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint. The fingerprint is the sequence of 20
>   two-digit hexadecimal numbers separated by colons.

What I am using is this:

```
Jaime-MontoyaMacBook:.android jaimemontoya$ keytool -printcert -list -keystore /Users/[my username]/[my folders]/key -alias jaime
Enter keystore password:  
jaime, May 24, 2019, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): [SHA-256 value...]
Jaime-MontoyaMacBook:.android jaimemontoya$
```

Why is it that I do not see the `SHA1`? It is only displaying the `SHA-256`. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Google map still blank on real Android device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question received an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56307654/4242086. The Stack Overflow website does not offer a way for me to mark it as answered if I just post the link because it considered the answer trivial and moved it as a comment, so I had to add extra redundant text here but I already have an answer to this question. Thank you.